# WebApi hosted on Azure isn't returning content on 401

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

I have an action in my AuthController that returns status code 202/401/403 depending on the user's status (ok, not yet approved or unexistent).

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage GetAuthenticate(string identifier)
{
    try
    {
        var user = membership.Login(identifier);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, user);
    }
    catch (UserNotApprovedException)
    {
        var user = membership.GetUserByProviderKey(identifier);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, user);
    }
    catch (EntityNotFoundException)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden));
    }
}
```

While running it locally it works as expected, but on Azure Webrole the 401 comes without any content (content-length = 0).

In the first case (user approved, 202) it does return the user...